# Return using presentingViewController with for loop

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

If 5 screen transitions and return to first, will the code as below work properly?

```
var now_Page: Int = 5 /// now 5 pages

for i in now_Page{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) /// back 5 pages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back more than one screen, you should use an unwind segue. Set one up in the storyboard editor and then do:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self)
```